# To find sum of 5 55 555 5555 .... n using python

Tags: python

We need to find the sum of the following number to a given range n which describes is n=5 then the last term will be 55555.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: so for `n=3` the last term is `333` or `33333` ?

Comment: Usually code without *any* attempts is downvoted fast, so I guess everyone is in good mood today :)

Comment: @OrenIshShalom from the question title i suspect the last term for n=3 would be 555.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mul` operator to repeat the digit, convert back to an integer and sum.

```
def find_sum(digit, max_repeats):
    return sum(int(str(digit)*(i+1)) for i in range(max_repeats))

print(find_sum(5, 5))
#output 61725
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the idea from the following algorithm:

```
def sum(n):
    # This will be multiplied.
    nbr=0
    # This will be the return value.
    ret=0
    for i in range(0, n):
        # Every iteration this will add 1 to the nbr: 1, 11, 111, etc.
        nbr = nbr + 10 ** i
        # Multiply by 5 and sum with the previous value: 5 + 55 + 555 + etc.
        ret = nbr * 5 + ret
    print(ret)
```